# What is the best way to populate the combobox dojo (1.8) programmatically?

Tags: javascript, json, dojo, javascript-framework

Hello I have sought the best way to populate a combobox with data from my database. I tried it this way, but I think there are better ways to do it in JavaScript.

Thank you all

```
var albumStore = new JsonRest({target:"/album", idAttribute:"id"});
var store = new Memory();

albumStore.query('').then(function(data) {

    json = new Array();
    for(i in data){
        item = {
            name: data[i].nome,
            id: data[i].id
        }
        json[i] = item;
    }
    store .setData(json);
})

props =  {
    required : true,
    missingMessage: 'campo obrigatório',
    store: store
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array slice method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to [clone arrays](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-clone-array):

```
var restStore = new JsonRest({ target: "/album/", idProperty: "Key" });
var memoryStore = new Memory({ idProperty: "Key" });

restStore.query().then(function(response) {
    memoryStore.setData(response.slice(0));
});
```

Please note, you can also use `JsonRest` store directly with `ComboBox`, if your REST server supports it. See how it works with [fakeServer](http://sinonjs.org/docs/#fakeServer) of [sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/) at this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/N8DqG/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that store in your case is ItemFileWriteStore, replace the following code:

```
json = new Array();
                for(i in data){
                    item = {
                        name: data[i].nome,
                        id: data[i].id
                    }
                    json[i] = item;
                }
                store .setData(json);
```

with the newItem API of store as shown below

```
            for(i in data){
                item = {
                    store.newItem({id: data[i].id, name: data[i].name});
                }
            }
```

Similarly, there is API for deleting items from store.

```
store.deleteItem(item);
```